# If someone in freefall towards earth used a telescope to look at someone in a spaceship accelerating at 10m/s/s, would they see their clock run fast?

Tags: general-relativity, reference-frames, acceleration, time-dilation, observers

Basically I'm quite confused about relativity haha. I've been told that the only two things that affect whether you'll observe someone else's clock ticking at a different rate than yours are

1. Your relative velocities
2. The difference between the strength of the gravitational fields you're in.

Here's my confusion. If you were in freefall, accelerating at 10m/s/s, and you looked through a telescope at someone in a spaceship accelerating at 10/s/s, you might not see them moving at all (relative to you). But you would be in earth's gravitational field and they would not - so would you see their clock ticking more quickly than yours?

Comment: maybe the description of the use of both special and general relativity to get the correct coordinates for GPS will help in understanding? https://www.astronomy.ohio-state.edu/pogge.1/Ast162/Unit5/gps.html